# Копировать строку из файла до пробела (используются <stdio.h.> и <string.h>)

Tags: c

Имеются две структуры:

```
struct horse
{
    char* name; 
    float horseMiddleTime, *horseTime;
};

struct road
{
    int countCircles, countHorse;
    horse* member;
};

FILE* stream;
horse rec;
road road1;
```

И внешний файл `base.txt`, заполняемый данной функцией:

```
void addHorseToBase(horse& rec, FILE* stream)
{
    fopen_s(&stream, "base.txt", "a");
    srand(time(0));
    cout << "Enter horse's name: ";
    cin >> rec.name;
    fputc('\n', stream);
    fputs(rec.name, stream);
    fputc(' ', stream);
    rec.horseMiddleTime = (rand() % 100)*0.01 + 30;
    rec.horseMiddleTime += (rand() % 16);
    fprintf(stream, "%.2f ", rec.horseMiddleTime);
    fclose(stream);
}
```

В нем хранятся имена лошадей и их среднее время за круг. Выглядит так:

```
lucky 43.30 
pretty 38.51 
ginger 41.77 
good 32.00 
brave 34.13 
strong 40.35
```

Нужно скопировать из `base.txt` в `road1.member[0].name` строку до пробела - к примеру `lucky`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для чтение используются [`fread`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fread) и [`fscanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf).

К примеру, кусочек для чтения строки будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
char *horse_name;
double horse_time;

// выделение памяти

fscanf(stream, "%s %lf\n", &horse_name, &horse_time);

// потом скопировать в road1.member[0].name
```

---

В дополнение есть смысл и запись переписать через [`fprintf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf).

Comment: Хм. А как узнать заранее, сколько памяти выделить под `horse_name`? :-P

Comment: @VladD А это уже следующий вопрос!

Comment: у меня есть подозрение, что честно это сделать, оставаясь в рамках вашего кода, невозможно, и надо использовать `getline`/`sscanf`.

Comment: Почему? Всё-равно это чтение будет в цикле, просто добавить поиск следующего пробела, а `fteel` скажет нужный размер. В случае с `getline` всё-равно надо будет выделять память под строку.

Comment: Хм. `ftell`? Ничего не понял. Может лучше покажите код?

Comment: Я имел ввиду примерно такое: http://ideone.com/Fdsjz3. В случае с `getline` тоже надо будет как-то память для строки выделять.

Comment: `malloc(pos_end - pos)` — это как-то пессимистично :) если файл будет размером в гигабайт с короткими строками, мы на каждую строку будем заводить по гигабайтному буферу.

Comment: По поводу [POSIX `getline`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html): If `*lineptr` is set to `NULL` and `*n` is set 0 before the call, then `getline()` will allocate a buffer for storing the line. То есть `getline` сам выделит память (а он знает, сколько надо).

Comment: А почему гигабайтному? Там же разница. Да, похоже что с `getline` таки решение лучше...